# Turn Site into a PDF

Tags: wordpress, pdf

I have a wordpress site about 25 pages, is it possible to click and make a PDF from the whole site ?

Comment: you can add a link to each page that turns a page into a PDF - see http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/save-as-pdf - i don't think you can convert the WHOLE site into one PDF

Answer (score 1):

You can write a program using http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/ make a button working off a click event. But i'm guessing you want to click a button already made some where to convert your pages to PDF's. In that case have you Googled `HTML to PDF` I see a whole bunch of websites that convert web pages to PDF's for free

Comment: i never think about searching for html2pdf but did not find any free online solution yet ! no pc soft and no money !

Comment: Are you telling me you have searched Google for "HTML to PDF" and found no free services that convert HTML documents (pages) to PDF?

Comment: I did not find free services, and i search for : free website to pdf converter online, and found that acrobat pro is doing that... for a 25 pages site, it take more than 2h

Comment: Did you really not find any? I see quite a few http://awesomescreenshot.com/06cjdm268 what is the problem with these?

Answer (score -1):

after research, here is what i have found. Adobe Acrobat Pro have that BUILD IN. reference : http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1252827&seqNum=3%C2%A0 and http://www.pdfforlawyers.com/2005/12/how_to_create_a.html. information date back from 2005 and 2008!